# How to get shared message for the URL with Facebook graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know i can get the shared count with something like this

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com
```

but is it possible to get the message from facebook, what they post with the shared link ? For example i shared stackoverflow[.]com and i post the message "it's useful !!". How can i collect all the message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the graph explorer to retrieve this, the message will be included as part of the returned object, but you should pass that link_id. If you use FQL, then you can query the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/links/) table and the owner_comment field will get you that data.